# How to make an iframe responsive full height and full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm embedding a youtube/dailymotion videos and I want to make the iframe responsive and especially full height , the same height as the window :

I made a responsive Iframe but not full height !

Here is my code

```
   <div  class="video-container">
                       <iframe height="100%" width="100%"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7ipiybRLqZc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
                </div>
```

CSS :

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    height:100%;

}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
}
```

[DEMO + CODE JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2rg09xsg/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [**viewport percentage lengths**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths), `vw` and `vh` to set the height and width of the `iframe`. Optionally, use `calc` to subtract `4px` as the player seems to add this.

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of
>   viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only
>   Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values dynamically,
>   when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of
>   the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone
>   or a tablet).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
iframe {
  height:calc(100vh - 4px);
  width:calc(100vw - 4px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7ipiybRLqZc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2ro1kyer/)

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="h_iframe">
        <!-- a transparent image is preferable -->
        <img class="ratio" src="http://placehold.it/16x9" />
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WsFWhL4Y84Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
margin:0;
}

.h_iframe {
    position:relative;
}
.h_iframe .ratio {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.h_iframe iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```