# responsive full screen iframe undistinguishable

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am using an iFrame inside a page and trying to make user feel that the iframe is the main original page.
There are bunch of questions abt it here but they are not working as I expected.
I have already checked and follwed all the relative topics about full screen responsice iframe. but for no reason I can figure, It is not working.
I have used this method for example
[How to make an iframe responsive full height and full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070963/how-to-make-an-iframe-responsive-full-height-and-full-width)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
iframe {
  height:calc(100vh - 4px);
  width:calc(100vw - 4px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7ipiybRLqZc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but still when I switch to smart phone view, the webpage is not being shown as mobile version and it is not responsive.
This is the page with an Iframe in it:
https://alumsharif.org/testProfile.php

and the iFrame source it self is this page:
https://alumsharif.org/people/alireza.ghaderi

as you can see the original page works as expected and mobile version works. but when I ue the first URL, mobile version is bot being activated on mobile view.
What step am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I see your page as responsive, at around 995px width it switches from full navbar-like menu to the hamburger menu, and it looks fine on all mobile devices (emulators) listed in Chrome.

Comment: @tromgy I just added two screenshots in the main question. the right picture is the real src page and the left pic is the exact page placed in the iframe. As you can see the one on the left is not switched to the mobile version. only the menu collapsed to burger mode